# Is there a way to link a part of text in DetailPrint in NSIS script to point to a file?

Tags: nsis

Example:
DetailPrint "Errors detected running post installation scripts. Click here to view the results."

Clicking on "here" should take user to specific file"

Answer (score 0):

The log window is just a ListView control and it does not support this.

You can display a message to the user:

```
Section
; Post install steps...
MessageBox MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION "There was a problem, view results?" /SD IDNO IDNO skipresults
    ExecShell "" "$Temp\InstallError.log"
skipresults:
SectionEnd
```

Or you can display a custom page with a link on it:

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Page Directory
Page InstFiles
Page Custom myPostFailureCreate


Var PostFailure

Function OpenPostReport
ExecShell ...
FunctionEnd

Function myPostFailureCreate
${If} $PostFailure = 0
    Abort
${EndIf}

nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 5u 0 80% 12u "Install scripts failed!"
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateLink} 5u 13u 80% 12u "View report"
Pop $1
${NSD_OnClick} $1 OpenPostReport
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Section
; Post install steps...
${If} ${Errors}
    StrCpy $PostFailure 1
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```